# Getting inner class type name

Tags: java, class, inner-classes, anonymous-inner-class

I'm trying to get the name of a type (which is an interface) that is instantiated within a class but the available methods I've tried do not return the actual name of the type.

Example:

To get the name I would do:

```
class Test {

    void test(Object o) {
        System.out.println(o.getClass());
    }

}
```

Taking the java.lang.Runnable interface for example:

```
...
test(new Runnable() {});
```

Would print out something like `class test.Test$2`,  I've tried other methods in the Class class but they just print out null or `test.Test`. How would I be able to get `class java.lang.Runnable` from it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an inner anonymous class, you can do as follows:

```
void test(Object o) {
    if(o.getClass().isAnonymousClass()) {
      System.out.println(o.getClass().getInterfaces()[0].getName());
    } else {
      System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());
    }        
}
```

Comment: Does this work if you change `Inner` to be an interface instead of a class?

Comment: @EmilH It should, if you provide an anonymous implementation of Inner to `test`.

Comment: Tried it out with an interface and in that case it prints `java.lang.Object`. By using `getInterfaces` it would be possible to get the `Class` representation of the interface `o`'s class implements.

Comment: @EmilH The question there is, which interface to take. Of course, one can just take either only the first, or use `Arrays.toString()`.

Comment: It does seem a bit "haxy" but it works nonetheless, thanks! By the way, typo at [0]()

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by simply doing an `instanceof` check:

```
void test(Object o) {
    System.out.println(o instanceof Runnable);
}
```

This will print `true` in case the object implements the Runnable interface.

If you want a more dynamic solution (for instance if you wanted to print all the interfaces of the Object `o` ) you'd have to do something like:

```
void test(Object o) {
    for (Class i : o.getClass().getInterfaces()) {
        System.out.println(i.getName());
    }
}
```